# segmentation fault array float in ubuntu but not osx

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, malloc, ubuntu-14.04

If I compile this code with gcc on osx and I run it, it works perfectly... indeed, if I compile the same code on ubuntu (gcc version: 4.8.2) and I run it, I have a segmentation fault error. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROW 64
#define COL 16  

int readMyFile(float*, char**);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  float *array;
  array = (float*) malloc (ROW*COL*sizeof(float));

  r = readMyFile(array,argv);
  if(r) return r;

  free(array);

  return 0;
}


int readMyFile(float *array, char* argv[]) {

   FILE *ifp;
   float tmp;
   short i=0;

   ifp=fopen(argv[1], "r");

   if(ifp==NULL)
     return 1;

   while(fscanf(ifp, "%f", &tmp) == 1)
   {
      printf("i: %d\n",i);
      array[i]=tmp;
      i++;
   }
   fclose(ifp);
   return 0;
}
```

I compile the code above, using the command on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS: `gcc -o Test Test.c`
After, I run with this command: `./Test myfile.txt`

The content of `myfile.txt` is like this:

-4
0
-3
-2
2
0
2
0
1
.
.
.
and so on

In my opinion, the problem could be in this point: `matrix[i]=tmp;` why?

Comment: how do you plan to limit the `i` in `array[i]`?

Comment: Use a debugger i.e. GDB.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, why you need to limit "i" in array[i]?

Comment: @GAM otherwise, it might overrun the allocated memory, producing UB, giving segfault, causing pain....

Comment: @SouravGhosh, the file is read for sure. That's not the problem.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, segfault error occurs at line 1060 of myfile.txt. The file contains 2000000 lines

Comment: 2000000 > 64*16 and also `short i`

Comment: `if(r) return r` - you need to `free(array)` before you `return r`.

Comment: @barakmanos With this modification does not change anything.. :(

Comment: @GAM: It's not supposed to solve the main problem that you're dealing with, but it's a warning worth paying attention to.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 places where you should add error handling:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  float *array;
  array = (float*) malloc (ROW*COL*sizeof(float));

  // Added check that malloc succeded.
  if (array == NULL) return 1;  // Failed to allocate memory

  r = readMyFile(array,argv);
  if(r) return r;

  free(array);

  return 0;
}


int readMyFile(float *array, char* argv[]) {

   FILE *ifp;
   float tmp;
   int i=0;    // Change type to int to be able to handle larger sizes.

   ifp=fopen(argv[1], "r");

   if(ifp==NULL)  // Good!
     return 1;

   while(fscanf(ifp, "%f", &tmp) == 1)
   {
      // Added check that there is room in array.
      if (i >= ROW * COL) return 1;  // Too many values in the file!
      printf("i: %d\n",i);
      array[i]=tmp;
      i++;
   }
   fclose(ifp);
   return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

Apparently the file contains more than 64*16 values, so in this case the code will bail due to too many values in the file.

Comment: the strange thing is that the program above on osx works without the controls that you have added

Comment: @GAM: Matter of chance. Writing into `array` beyond the boundaries of the memory allocated to it yields undefined behavior.

Comment: @GAM: Semantically, I would recommend that you pass `argv[1]` instead of `argv` to function `readMyFile(float* array, char* fileName)`.

Comment: @GAM: In addition, as I have already mentioned in a comment to your question, in `if(r) return r`,ou need to `free(array)` before you `return r`.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck I tried to run the code with your changes ... the execution ends the reading of the line 1023 of the file. And the other lines? how do I continue to read them?